# ifelse statement returning error in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

looking to create a binary indicator variable for a t.test and I am getting an error.

```
  fd <- fd %>%
    mutate(Con = ifelse(Intro1 != 2 | Intro1 != 4,0,
           ifelse(Intro2 != 2 | Intro2 != 4, 1,"NA")))
```

Error: incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector

```
    > str(fd$Intro2 )
    int [1:6299] NA NA NA 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
    > str(fd$Intro1 )
    int [1:6299] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Is it because of the nas? I tried

```
  fd <- fd %>%
        select(c(Intro1 , Intro2)) %>%
        na.omit  %>%
        mutate(Con = ifelse(Intro1 != 2 | Intro1 != 4,0,
             ifelse(Intro2 != 2 | Intro2 != 4, 1,"NA")))
```

Essentially what I would like to do is loop through all the rows and apply a 0 if Intro1 is not 2 or 4, and a 1 if Intro2 is not 2 or 4.

Comment: Try `mutate(Con=as.numeric(all(Intro1 %in% c(2,4), Intro2 %in% c(2,4))))`.  Also, you should use `NA`, not `"NA"`, otherwise it will convert the whole variable to character format.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, it definitely works, however, I believe it does not give a 0 if it is in Intro1 and a 1 if it is Intro2

Comment: Sorry - I didn't read the question properly! Now I have re-read it, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. `Intro1 != 2 | Intro1 !=4` will always be true - any number is either not equal to 2 or not equal to 4!

Comment: I see, great point, usually in VBA I would use brackets to avoid that problem. So in Intro1 (and 2), there are numeric values from 1-5, as well as NA, when the value is not 2 or 4 I would like the Con var to be 0 in Intro1 and 1 in Intro2. Sorry if I did not explain adequately.

Comment: I see! I think this might be what you need... `mutate(Con = ifelse(!(Intro1 %in% c(2,4)), 0, ifelse(!(Intro2 %in% c(2,4)), 1, NA)))`

Comment: The implementation of "not 2 or 4" may be either `! Intro %in% c (2,4)` or `Intro1 != 2 & Intro1 != 4`. (Andrew beat me by 35 seconds)

Comment: Think it worked! You guys, are the best, I did have to change it to     mutate(Con = ifelse(!(Intro1 %in% c(1,3,5)), 0, ifelse(!(Intro2 %in% c(1,3,5)), 1, NA)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr `case_when` syntax (which might be more readable than nested `ifelse` statements):

```
> fd <- data_frame(Intro1 = c(NA,NA,NA, 1:5), Intro2 = c(NA,1:5, NA,NA))
> fd %>% mutate(Con = case_when(
     ! Intro1 %in% c(2,4) ~ 0,
     ! Intro2 %in% c(2,4) ~ 1
 ))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Intro1 Intro2   Con
   <int>  <int> <dbl>
1     NA     NA     0
2     NA      1     0
3     NA      2     0
4      1      3     0
5      2      4    NA
6      3      5     0
7      4     NA     1
8      5     NA     0
```

Comment: Interesting, I have the Dplyr package, but RStudio cannot find case_when.

Comment: is was introduced in dplyr 0.5.0, you can check your package version using `packageVersion("dplyr")`

Comment: So I should reinstall? Seems to not be in my version. I like your solution.

Comment: ‘0.4.3’ is the version

Comment: I did that, but getting error - Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  incompatible size (6299), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1

Comment: well, your specific data might be the reason... would you share on https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not, however, I tried your code and it works, so I will mark as correct.